# Connected manifold

Tags: analysis

I need to prove a rather simple fact: let $X$ be a connected smooth (or just topological) manifold. Now we need to prove that $X$ is linearly connected.
So, it seems to be obvious, because $X$ is locally like a unit open ball in $\mathbb{R}^n$, but i cannot get clear proof.

Comment: Is "linearly connected" the same as "path connected"?

Comment: Yes, it is, i am sorry for terminology, i just translated it from russian word-to-word.

Comment: A good general strategy is to use the fact that you find it obvious to figure out how you know it's true. Here, I'd ask how being locally like an open unit ball means it should be linearly connected

Answer (score 0):

You have the right idea. Just show that that being linearly connected is an open condition (i.e. every point has a neighborhood that is linearly connected). Then the `linearly connected components' of the space form a decomposition into disjoint open sets. Here the`linearly connected components' are the maximal subsets that are linearly connected.